# Remove some factor-interaction terms from estimation

Tags: r, r-factor

I'd like to remove certain factor interactions from an estimation. Here's an example with generated data from an imaginated labour market (I uploaded it here: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=EcMEVqUC)

```
s <- source("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=EcMEVqUC")$value

lm(income ~ age + cit * prof, data=s)
```

In this example economy, foreigners are not allowed to work in the public sector, therefore `citforeign:profofficial` is `NA`. Therefore I would like to exclude the interaction term of `citforeign:profofficial`. But keep all other interactions.

As I understand factors as multiple dummy variables stored in one column I don't think there's a logic problem with that?

(How) can I achieve this?

[edit]
A one step-solution would be great as I would want to use it with `stepAIC()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use function `update`.

```
model1 <- lm(income ~ age + cit * prof, data=s)
model2 <- update(model1, . ~ . - citforeign:profofficial)
```

Comment: nice! Is this also possible in one step? ... I know I was not asking for that but I would like to use `stepAIC()`

Comment: @speendo then write your model by hand, sensu the offending interaction.