# How to prevent or remove or replace NA values in glm output statistics?

Tags: r, dataframe, glm, mass

I've made up an example to illustrate my problem. Imagine I have a dataset, and I train a generalized linear model with gamma-distributed residuals.

```
library(MASS)

df <- read.csv('test.csv')

model <- glm(formula = y ~ method * site + year + 0,
             family=Gamma(link = "log"), data = df)
```

And I get something that looks like this:

```
> summary(model) 

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)
methodM0          3.89533    0.13670  28.496  < 2e-16 ***
methodM1          5.63965    0.20940  26.933  < 2e-16 ***
methodM2        -55.854107  73.982453  -0.755    0.450
methodM3        -55.731730  73.986509  -0.753    0.451
siteS1           -0.002872   0.098226  -0.029    0.977
siteS2            0.060892   0.107795   0.565    0.572
siteS3           -0.016239   0.102258  -0.159    0.874
year              0.030813   0.036743   0.839    0.402
methodM1:siteS1  -0.030616   0.144592  -0.212    0.832
methodM2:siteS1  -0.030632   0.144663  -0.212    0.832
methodM3:siteS1   0.064179   0.145593   0.441    0.659
methodM1:siteS2  -0.146505   0.152012  -0.964    0.335
methodM2:siteS2  -0.039610   0.148024  -0.268    0.789
methodM3:siteS2  -0.202881   0.150406  -1.349    0.178
methodM1:siteS3   NA         NA         NA       NA
methodM2:siteS3   0.081617   0.144040   0.567    0.571
methodM3:siteS3  -0.064155   0.147771  -0.434    0.664
```

The table is the result of made-up numbers, but the point is that I have an interaction between method M1 and site S3 that give `NA`. How can I setup the GLM to not calculate that particular interaction, remove that interaction after training, or set those NA values in the model to `0`?

## Update

@jared_mamrot gave an answer that pointed to [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914249/remove-some-factor-interaction-terms-from-estimation) which is very similar:

```
s <- source("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=EcMEVqUC")$value

lm(income ~ age + cit * prof, data=s)
```

Here `lm` rather than `glm` is followed, but I found that update didn't even seem to fix this example when I ran the accepted answer to the related problem.

```
model1 <- lm(income ~ age + cit * prof, data=s)
model2 <- update(model1, . ~ . - citforeign:profofficial)
```

Looking at `model1`, we have

```
> model1

Call:
lm(formula = income ~ age + cit * prof, data = s)

Coefficients:
               (Intercept)                         age                     citwest                  citforeign  
                  2205.231                      -3.825                      74.871                      30.066  
           profblue-collar                profofficial     citwest:profblue-collar  citforeign:profblue-collar  
                  -189.146                    -147.332                      27.792                     -60.223  
      citwest:profofficial     citforeign:profofficial  
                  -122.220                          NA
```

And looking at `model2` we have the same

```
> model1

Call:
lm(formula = income ~ age + cit * prof, data = s)

Coefficients:
               (Intercept)                         age                     citwest                  citforeign  
                  2205.231                      -3.825                      74.871                      30.066  
           profblue-collar                profofficial     citwest:profblue-collar  citforeign:profblue-collar  
                  -189.146                    -147.332                      27.792                     -60.223  
      citwest:profofficial     citforeign:profofficial  
                  -122.220                          NA
```

As you can see, `update` doesn't seem to remove the `NA`.

Answer (score 0):

Can you use `update`? E.g.

```
model1 <- glm(formula = y ~ method * site + year + 0,
             family=Gamma(link = "log"), data = df)
model2 <- update(model1, . ~ . - methodM1:siteS3)
```

(per [Remove some factor-interaction terms from estimation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914249/remove-some-factor-interaction-terms-from-estimation) / https://www.r-bloggers.com/using-the-update-function-during-variable-selection/)

**Edit**

Here is a way to use the `update` method on the example data posted at [Remove some factor-interaction terms from estimation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914249/remove-some-factor-interaction-terms-from-estimation)

```
s <- source("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=EcMEVqUC")$value
model1 <- glm(income ~ age + cit * prof, data=s)
model2 <- update(model1, . ~ . - cit:prof)
summary_glm(model1)
summary_glm(model2)
```

**Edit 2**

If you don't want to use update you could try dropping the interaction (see below) but I don't know how this will affect the validity of the model or whether it is advisable.

```
s <- source("http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=EcMEVqUC")$value
model1 <- glm(income ~ age + cit * prof, data=s)
model2 <- glm(income ~ model.matrix(model1)[,1:9], data=s)
summary_glm(model1)
summary_glm(model2)
```

Comment: I tried using `update` with both my example and the on from [Remove some factor-interaction terms from estimation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16914249/remove-some-factor-interaction-terms-from-estimation) and I didn't find that the `NA` was removed.

Comment: The `NA`  coefficient for the `citforeign:profofficial` interaction from `"http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=EcMEVqUC"` is a perfect example, so let's use that. How do I get rid of the `NA` for specifically `citforeign:profofficial`?

Comment: Assuming we use `glm`.

Comment: Hi @Galen, updated my answer to provide a solution - hopefully this is what you're looking for, otherwise I'm out of ideas.